# Is there a do-while loop in GDscript?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Is there a `do ... while (condition)` loop in GDscript? The documentation [explains `while`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html?#while) but makes no mention of `do while`.

I have some code that I want to execute at least once, and then continue looping until a condition is met. Using a plain `while` is insufficient because it may not execute at all depending on the value of the condition at the start.

The editor tells me that the following is invalid:

```
  do:
      # a bunch of stuff
  while (condition == true)
```

Do I need to duplicate the "bunch of stuff" (or replace with function call) and run it once directly and *then* loop with a `while` loop (and remember to change both every time I change the code), or is there a do-while-equivalent structure in GDScript?

Comment: [This page](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-do-while-loop-example/) suggests to do a "while true", then at the end, check your condition and "break" if the condition is met. I understand having a "real" do-while loop would be the best solution, but that other option might be a bit cleaner than some other.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize Python also doesn't have a do while. That led me to https://stackoverflow.com/q/743164/866022, which presents a couple options that I think should work for emulating this type of loop.

Comment: You can always replace a `do-while` with a simple `while`, so I guess there is no explicit need for such a construct.

Comment: @QBrute yes, but having language-level support for "do this at least once" is nice. It's not a huge pain (there are fairly simple workarounds), just a minor annoyance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a `do ... while (condition)` loop in GDscript?

There isn't. The documentation does not mention anything like that, as you found out.

---

> I have some code that I want to execute at least once, and then continue looping until a condition is met.

You can do something like this:

```
while true:
    # some other code
    if condition:
        break
```

You, of course, don't have to use `break` at the end. You can use this approach to exit early at any point of the loop.

---

> Do I need to duplicate the "bunch of stuff" (or replace with function call) and run it once directly and then loop with a while loop (and remember to change both every time I change the code), or is there a do-while-equivalent structure in GDScript?

Unrolling the first iteration before the loop is viable too, however there isn't much point in doing that in GDScript. And yes, making a function is also an option, which you could call once before the loop. Something like this:

```
iteration()
while not condition:
    iteration()
```

If you are considering making a function, consider also having it return a `bool`, and in the function you can exit early with `return`. You would then use it like this:

```
while iterate():
    pass
```

And if you really want to over-engineer this… Although Godot does not have proper generator functions, it is possible to make a [custom iterator](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_advanced.html#custom-iterators).

*But why? Use `break`, it is fine.*

Comment: Although I don't disagree with just using `break`, I do think there's readability-improvements to having an iterator function. At least it's a useful pattern in Python, haven't tried it yet in Godot - but about to.

Comment: @Cyclops if by iteration function you mean a generator, GDScript does not have them (although GDScript has coroutines, they do not make up an iterator). The custom iterator you can make in GDScript is a class.

Comment: Theraot,  looking at that doc, it says it can be used in a for-loop. Yeah, you have to do an `iterator.new()` first, but close enough.